# I want to add dynamic labels to a set of boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

Please forgive me for the sloppiness of this question, as I am brand spankin' new to stack overflow.

So basically I want to add labels to a system of boxplots I have set up in R. These are using eye tracking data which records eye focus based on x and y position on a fixed screen.

[image]

In the above example, I want to put a number next to each of those boxplots representing the amount of time that the person spent not looking at the screen, resulting in missing data. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I've been using manipulate and ggplot2 successfully so far, but I just can't seem to find a method that works for my particular needs. I'll show you an *extremely small* data set to give you an idea of what I'm working with:

```
Subject    Time    Drive    Stimuli    GazeX    GazeY
1          526.10  6        E2         719.1975 696.4445
1          526.12  6        E2         717.1129 696.6486
6          530.83  5        A          716.9166 913.4790
6          530.85  5        A          716.9121 913.6028
10         631.55  6        N3         698.2593 573.6330
10         631.56  6        N3         710.7646 581.1820
16         0.1500  4        N          698.2593 573.6330
16         0.1667  4        N          710.7646 581.1820
25         128.08  7        T1         688.7745 634.5504
25         128.10  7        T1         690.3805 635.9002
40         783.92  5        N2         1178.798 248.8600
40         783.93  5        N2         NA       NA
```

For this code, it's basically a manipulate of 8 different boxplots

```
par(mfcol=c(2,4))

manipulate(
  c(
#Create a boxplot based off a drive value of 4 following the x-coordinates
  boxplot(
  formula = value ~ Stimuli,
  data    = dat.x4,
  outline = FALSE,
  boxwex  = 0.25,
  #subctr is a picker object in manipulate that filters the data based on the selected subject number
  subset  = c(Subject == subctr & Drive == "4"),
  main    = paste("T0",subctr," 4LD1 X-Position",sep=""),
  xlab    = "Stimuli",
  ylab    = "X-position Gaze"),

#Create a boxplot based off a drive value of 4 following the y-coordinates
  boxplot(
  formula = value ~ Stimuli,
  data    = dat.y4,
  outline = FALSE,
  boxwex  = 0.25,
  subset  = c(Subject == subctr & Drive == "4"),
  main    = paste("T0",subctr," 4LD1 Y-Position",sep=""),
  xlab    = "Stimuli",
  ylab    = "Y-position Gaze"),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 5, following x-coordinates),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 5, following y-coordinates),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 6, following x-coordinates),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 6, following y-coordinates),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 7, following x-coordinates),

  boxplot(#Same as above, for Drive value of 7, following y-coordinates))
```

I need the code to keep this dynamic picker thing going because I have 25 different subjects with well over 4 million lines of data. That means I have 25 different systems of boxplots like the one I linked, all dynamically manipulated.

Also, in case you are confused by dat.x4 or lines like that, I'll include how I am playing with the data. Keep in mind that I worked for several days trying to find a way to make the boxplots look the way I needed them to look, so while I am open to suggestions to improve this nastiness, I really do need the data to be arranged exactly like it is or at least very similarly.

```
library(reshape)
my.data <- read.csv("gazecsv1.csv", na.strings = "NaN") 
my.data <- gazecsv1

#This is repeated 8 times to have enough different data sets to  show the data I need shown in each boxplot.
dat.x4 <- melt(my.data,id.vars=c("Drive", "Stimuli", "Subject"), measure.vars="GazeX")
dat.x4$Stimuli = factor(dat.x4$Stimuli, c("N"))
```

Comment: I don't fully understand. Could you show how the desired output shood look?

Comment: I've added a basic example for what I'm looking for

Comment: Please distil your question down. This is a lot of code to which we have no access to data. Simulate  a small dataset and state clearly where and what you want to write.

Comment: And please explain why it ggplot is no option. geom_text sounds exactly what you need.

Comment: Also, you might have an easier time by combining all the data into one table with a column to indicate the group, and using `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` rather than 8 calls to `boxplot`.

Comment: @Philip Hmm, I am still pretty new to r, so I am not sure how that works. I'll probably do some research on that and see what I can do with it.

Comment: @bdecaf I thought that, but what I'm having problems with is making it to where the numbers change. For example, I have a picker that shows the data for a chosen subject. When I used geom_text, the values below the boxplots remained the same from when I selected, say, subject 1 first, then subject 4 next. The example above is only data for subject 1, and I need to switch between them and have everything shift dynamically.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have included a few lines of data. I need the boxplots to only show data from a specific subject, during a specific drive, and the boxplots represent the eye position during a specific stimuli.

Comment: With regard to `geom_text` not updating, the key is that you need your input data to regenerate dynamically. Can you try wrapping your input to manipulate in braces `{}` with a line that updates the data itself based on the manipulation, then pass that updated data to the plotting functions. This is effectively what happens in the base example here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate ; when I manipulate `x` in `plot(1:x)` I'm really passing a dynamic data object. See next comment

Comment: So you could try e.g. `manipulate({data <- [expression depending on subject]; plots(data)},manipulated inputs)`

Comment: Please _water down_ your example, not adding more information.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I'm not really sure how. If my problem could be simplified any more than it is, I could find my answer through google, which is what I've been using thus far.

I can try though.

Comment: I'm still trying to find time to work out an implementation of @Philip 's suggestion though, so he might have given me what I need. I just don't know yet.

Comment: Something [like this](https://twitter.com/Shakiguani/status/716521180803497984)? Adding text to plots using ggplot2 is pretty straightforward. Faceting wouldn't be too big of a complication.